# How to group by with a condition that delete rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, sql-delete

I have a table that has three columns, ID, Company, Result, like this:

[image: Original Table]

What I want to do is to group by ID/Company with a condition, if the same ID has both "Found" and "Not Found" results in the same company, I want to see only the line where the result is "Found".

I should be able to have the results of the same subject in different companies but in case of having multiple rows of the combination ID/Company see only the lines where the result is "Found"

The expected result should be like this:

[image: Expected result]

How can I do that? It's sort of a group by combined with a delete.

Comment: Actually its preferred it you post data as formatted text, then we can copy and paste it out for testing (and you don't need to post an image).

Comment: Hello there, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question, so that you can get a suitable answer. Read the docs on how to [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your explanation is a bit hard to follow, but based on your data I think that you just want aggregation and `min()`:

```
select id, company, min(result) result
from mytable
group by id, company
```

Why this works is because, string-wise, `'Found'` is smaller than `'Not Found'` (because the former starts with a `'F'`, while the latter starts with `'N'`). So if both values are present in the group, `min()` returns `'Found'`. If only one value is present, it is returned as is.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I needed, worked great! Sorry for the explanation, english is not my native language, tried to explain it the best I could.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the results per `id`/`company`.  One relatively simple way is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.result = 'Found' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.company = t.company and t2.result = 'Found'
                 );
```

With an index on `(id, company, result)`, this might be the fastest approach.

You can also structure this as a prioritization:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by id, company
                          order by result   -- "Found" is before "Not Found"
                         ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Both of these allow you to return any number of columns - although for three columns and at most one row per company/id combination you can use an aggregation approach as GMB suggests.

Comment: Thanks! Tried both, yours and GMB, both worked great!

Comment: @GAF . . . I answered to be more general, in case you have additional columns that you want returned.  You should accept one of the answers.